# Apple Pay Cert Update | SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, applepay, sslhandshakeexception

I recently updated my 'Apple Pay Payment Processing' and 'Apple Pay Merchant Identity' cert and am now receiving the error:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
    .
    .
    .
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2020)
```

I have crawled all through forums and have tried the following solutions:

1.TLS 1.2 enabled and set as default. 1.0 and 1.1 disabled.

2.For Java 8 the following added for 256 decryption: {JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

3.cert added to the keystore

But I am still getting the same error. What else could be causing this issue? I am at a loss and any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check `keytool -list -v` -- does your client cert appear, plus any chain cert(s), in a PrivateKeyEntry (NOT TrustedCertEntry)? PS: Oracle Java 8 updates from 8u151 do not need the policy download, as explained on the newer page https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce-all-downloads.html .

Answer (score 1):

Enable java.net.debug system property, it should give you more details on the handshake failure

Comment: That's `javax.net.debug`. But yes, check if the alert is in response to ClientHello or to the second flight.